# OverAppBrowser for Ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic2, ionic3, cordova-plugins

Recently i saw this plugin:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/koein-cordova-plugin-overappbrowser

But its difficult to guess how to integrate in ionic or cordova since there is no ionic wrapper for it.

I tried:

```
declare let window: any;

if (window.cordova) {...}
```

but their sample code won't work.

Has anyone used or integrated this OverAppBrowser or is familiar with integration of it? 
I need alternative to InAppBrowser that can actually be rendered over the ionic view or set its height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) is a global variable that represents the current window in which the script is running. You do not need to declare it.
Since you're using it in a cordova application, the proper syntax will be :

```
(<any>window).oab = new OverAppBrowser(xxx);
```

Use  to keep the window dynamic.

Comment: When I do window.oab = new OverAppBrowser('http://www.google.com', 0, 100, 320, 320, true); It says 'OverAppBrowser' not defined.

Comment: Actually it worked on a real device. but i had to put 'declare let OverAppBrowser' under the imports.

Comment: It is a cordova plugin, therefore it will only work when cordova is available - which is on a real device. If this solved your question, accept this as the correct answer.

Comment: Yes I know that it will work only on a device, but I had to put 'declare let OverAppBrowser'  otherwise it is not recognized. Thanks.

Comment: if you have time could you check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53026911/open-ionic-page-in-the-top-of-the-themeable-inappbrowser-and-the-cordova-web-vie